# The integer part of RSA public key

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I am studying RSA cryptosystem. The public key consists of (n, e), an integer (product of two large primes), and encryption key. I want to separate the integer (n) and key (e). The typical public key is expressed in base64, and of the following type:

```
 -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

 MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0
 FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/
 3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQAB

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Now from the above key, it is not clear which part is integer and which one is encryption key. If someone can guide me, it would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Would be good to know why it is downvoted!

Comment: Because reading documentation for methods that produced that key representation would have given you the answer.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Think before writing. The OP could have received this by e-mail, read on the site etc.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp this question shows no research effort. Dumping base64 string and asking what does it means is not even a programing-related question, strictly speaking.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin The question is far from trivial for the person who studies cryptography. Personally for you: StackOverflow exists not for fondling one's self-esteem.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin As I said, I am starting off from textbook. I have had no idea of the existence of ASN.1 definition, that is the reason I asked. Why on earth, cryptography has to be connected to any particular programming language (as in one of your comments). I marked cryptography, precisely for this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Base64 of DER encoding of ASN.1 `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure, which is defined in [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) (check section 4.1 for ASN.1 definition and section 4.1.2.7 for additional textual description).

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
    subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING  }
```

The contents of `subjectPublicKey` field depend on the key algorithm which is specified by the `algorithm` field.

For RSA, it will be `RSAPublicKey` structure defined in [RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447)

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
      modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
      publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
  }
```

If your programming language of choice supports RSA encryption that most likely it provides a class or structure or other language-specific means to read generic `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` data and convert it into some representation that will allow access to RSA-specific data. For example, in Java

```java
byte[] bytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary( "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQAB" );

X509EncodedKeySpec genericKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec( bytes );
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance( "RSA" );
PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic( genericKeySpec );
RSAPublicKeySpec rsaKeySpec = factory.getKeySpec( publicKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class );
System.out.println( "n = " + rsaKeySpec.getModulus() );
System.out.println( "e = " + rsaKeySpec.getPublicExponent() );
```

Comment: Please, no `sun.misc.*`. They are going to be removed in a future release. Particularly now that, as of Java 8, there is `java.util.Base64`.

Comment: While a valid point in general, using `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` is sufficient to define the intent for that example without introducing a lot of explanations. The question is not even specific for any programming language.

Comment: Good point, but I'm concerned about those who copy-paste random snippets of code from the internet without fully understanding what they're doing. There are too many of those people. I wouldn't want the sun.misc plague to spread further now that there's a standard class for this.

Comment: replaced with a class available since 1.6.